# Android Studio Incompatible Types

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRLuEgzIk7A&index=1&list=PLZHVfZzF2DYLkx291MkZP0lA5n3Q3HKHl) to light on a LED with a phone. 
But I have an error in this code  :

```
package com.irobotechart.controlbt;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;

public class DevicesBT extends AppCompatActivity {

    //1)
    // Depuración de LOGCAT
    private static final String TAG = "DevicesBT"; //<-<- PARTE A MODIFICAR >->->
    // Declaracion de ListView
    ListView IdLista;
    // String que se enviara a la actividad principal, mainactivity
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    // Declaracion de campos
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices_bt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //---------------------------------
        VerificarEstadoBT();

        // Inicializa la array que contendra la lista de los dispositivos bluetooth vinculados
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.name_devices);//<-<- PARTE A MODIFICAR >->->
        // Presenta los disposisitivos vinculados en el ListView
        IdLista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.IdList);
        IdLista.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        IdLista.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
        // Obtiene el adaptador local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // Obtiene un conjunto de dispositivos actualmente emparejados y agregua a 'pairedDevices'
        Set pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // Adiciona un dispositivos previo emparejado al array
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0)
        {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }

    // Configura un (on-click) para la lista
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

            // Obtener la dirección MAC del dispositivo, que son los últimos 17 caracteres en la vista
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Realiza un intent para iniciar la siguiente actividad
            // mientras toma un EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS que es la dirección MAC.
            Intent i = new Intent(DevicesBT.this, UserInterface.class);//<-<- PARTE A MODIFICAR >->->
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    private void VerificarEstadoBT() {
        // Comprueba que el dispositivo tiene Bluetooth y que está encendido.
        mBtAdapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBtAdapter==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "El dispositivo no soporta Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth Activado...");
            } else {
                //Solicita al usuario que active Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is : Incompatible types : Found :'android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice', require: 'java.lang.Object'

I don't know how I can solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for your help

I hope to be clear, I'm sorry if there are mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a Raw-type `Set` instead of `generic` mean, while using collections you can define the type of data and if you don't define then the type will be of `Object`

so use

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

instead of

```
Set pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Note : remove `mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();` from `onresume` it's redundant, already done in `VerificarEstadoBT()`

---

Further Read

[What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)